# use d3 brush to select element in a linechart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, frontend

I am a beginner and I got a problem when I try to select some element in a lineChart.
I know there are so many elites, So I come here for some help :)
I find a brush demo in [there](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4560481) and a linechart(sorry they don't allow me to insert 2 links because I don't have 10 reputations) demo Then I write the code blow:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style type="text/css">
    /* 13. Basic Styling with CSS */

    /* Style the lines by removing the fill and applying a stroke */
    .line {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #ffab00;
        stroke-width: 3;
    }

    /* Style the dots by assigning a fill and stroke */
    .dot {
        fill: #1 fab40;
        stroke: #fff;
    }
    .dot .selected {
        stroke: red;
    }

</style>
<!-- Body tag is where we will append our SVG and SVG objects-->
<body>
</body>

<!-- Load in the d3 library -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

    // 2. Use the margin convention practice
    var margin = {top: 20, right: 50, bottom: 20, left: 50}
        , width = window.innerWidth - margin.left - margin.right // Use the window's width
        , height = window.innerHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom; // Use the window's height

    // The number of datapoints
    var n = 21;

    // 5. X scale will use the index of our data
    var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, n-1]) // input
        .range([0, width]); // output

    // 6. Y scale will use the randomly generate number
    var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, 1]) // input
        .range([height, 0]); // output

    // 7. d3's line generator
    var line = d3.line()
        .x(function(d, i) { return xScale(i); }) // set the x values for the line generator
        .y(function(d) { return yScale(d.y); }) // set the y values for the line generator
        .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX);// apply smoothing to the line

    // 8. An array of objects of length N. Each object has key -> value pair, the key being "y" and the value is a random number
    var dataset = d3.range(n).map(function(d) { return {"y": d3.randomUniform(1)() } });

    // 1. Add the SVG to the page and employ #2
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    // 3. Call the x axis in a group tag
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale)); // Create an axis component with d3.axisBottom

    // 4. Call the y axis in a group tag
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale)); // Create an axis component with d3.axisLeft

    // 9. Append the path, bind the data, and call the line generator
    svg.append("path")
        .datum(dataset) // 10. Binds data to the line
        .attr("class", "line") // Assign a class for styling
        .attr("d", line); // 11. Calls the line generator

    // 12. Appends a circle for each datapoint
    var dot = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "dot") // Assign a class for styling
        .selectAll(".dot")
        .data(dataset)
        .enter().append("circle") // Uses the enter().append() method
        .attr("r", 5)
        .attr("cx", function(d, i) { return xScale(i) })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return yScale(d.y) });

    var brush = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "brush")
        .call(d3.brush()
            .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
            .on("start brush end", brushed));

    function brushed() {
        var selection = d3.event.selection;
        dot.classed("selected", selection && function(d) {
            return selection[0][0] <= d.x && d.x < selection[1][0]
                && selection[0][1] <= d.y && d.y < selection[1][1];
        });
    }


</script>
```

I try to write the same code like [this demo](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4560481), But I can't selected any dot, Where is the problem?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your `brushed` function like this:

```
function brushed() {
    var selection = d3.event.selection;

    dot.classed("selected", selection && function(d,i) {
        return selection[0][0] <= xScale(i) && xScale(i) < selection[1][0]
            && selection[0][1] <= yScale(d.y) && yScale(d.y) < selection[1][1];
    });
}
```

Pay attention, we use `xScale` and `yScale` here, for correctly matching selected area and coordinates of dots. Working example is below:

```js
// 2. Use the margin convention practice
    var margin = {top: 20, right: 50, bottom: 20, left: 50}
        , width = window.innerWidth - margin.left - margin.right // Use the window's width
        , height = window.innerHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom; // Use the window's height

    // The number of datapoints
    var n = 21;

    // 5. X scale will use the index of our data
    var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, n-1]) // input
        .range([0, width]); // output

    // 6. Y scale will use the randomly generate number
    var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, 1]) // input
        .range([height, 0]); // output

    // 7. d3's line generator
    var line = d3.line()
        .x(function(d, i) { return xScale(i); }) // set the x values for the line generator
        .y(function(d) { return yScale(d.y); }) // set the y values for the line generator
        .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX);// apply smoothing to the line

    // 8. An array of objects of length N. Each object has key -> value pair, the key being "y" and the value is a random number
    var dataset = d3.range(n).map(function(d) { return {"y": d3.randomUniform(1)() } });

    // 1. Add the SVG to the page and employ #2
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    // 3. Call the x axis in a group tag
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale)); // Create an axis component with d3.axisBottom

    // 4. Call the y axis in a group tag
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale)); // Create an axis component with d3.axisLeft

    // 9. Append the path, bind the data, and call the line generator
    svg.append("path")
        .datum(dataset) // 10. Binds data to the line
        .attr("class", "line") // Assign a class for styling
        .attr("d", line); // 11. Calls the line generator

    // 12. Appends a circle for each datapoint
    var dot = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "dot") // Assign a class for styling
        .selectAll(".dot")
        .data(dataset)
        .enter().append("circle") // Uses the enter().append() method
        .attr("r", 5)
        .attr("cx", function(d, i) { return xScale(i) })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return yScale(d.y) });

    var brush = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "brush")
        .call(d3.brush()
          .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
          .on("start brush", brushed)
          .on("end", getSelectedDots)
        );
        
    var selectedDots = [];
    
    function getSelectedDots() {
        var selection = d3.event.selection;
       
        dot.classed("selected", selection && function(d,i) {
          var isSelectedDot = selection[0][0] <= xScale(i) && xScale(i) < selection[1][0]
                && selection[0][1] <= yScale(d.y) && yScale(d.y) < selection[1][1];
                
          if (isSelectedDot) {
            selectedDots.push(d);
          }

          return isSelectedDot;
        });
        
        console.log('selectedDots ', selectedDots);
    }

    function brushed() {
        var selection = d3.event.selection;
       
        dot.classed("selected", selection && function(d,i) {          
          return selection[0][0] <= xScale(i) && xScale(i) < selection[1][0]
                && selection[0][1] <= yScale(d.y) && yScale(d.y) < selection[1][1];
        });
    }
```

```css
/* 13. Basic Styling with CSS */

    /* Style the lines by removing the fill and applying a stroke */
    .line {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #ffab00;
        stroke-width: 3;
    }

    /* Style the dots by assigning a fill and stroke */
    .dot {
        fill: #1fab40;
        stroke: #fff;
    }
    .dot .selected {
        stroke: red;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.11.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks！！you are so kind

Comment: I am so sorry to bother you again ,Now I can select the dot which I need ,but all of them are coordinates of the SVG  What I really needed is the real data,How can I get them?

Comment: @lomo I rewrite code-snippet for my answer, take a look at it. Pay attention on `getSelectedDots` function, which I attach on `end` event of `d3.brush`. Now after every selection, the array of data-objects for selected dots appears on a console.